# How to compile and install Pidgin client and add Google Talk (~ Hangouts) into it?

Tags: pidgin, google-talk, google-hangouts

How does one compile and install Pidgin client and add Google Talk (~ Hangouts) into it on Ubuntu? Not only it is possible, but with relatively high security.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Google Hangout to Pidgin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019517/how-to-add-google-hangout-to-pidgin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a step-by-step guide on
**How to compile and install Pidgin and make it work with Google Talk (~ Hangouts) on Ubuntu**:
The differences between Hangouts and Google Talk you will find on this page:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/4564211
1. Enable 2-Step Verification on this page:
 https://accounts.google.com/SmsAuthConfig
[image: 2-Step Verification]
2. Generate a new App password for Pidgin on this page, select *Other* and name it however:
 https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
[image: App password]
3. Install the latest version of Pidgin for your system from this page:
https://pidgin.im/download/ or from repository of your Linux distribution or compile it from source (or for Max OS X they recommend using http://adium.im/)
4. To avoid security bugs, you should often check if your Ubuntu Linux repository contains the latest version available, which you may check on this page https://pidgin.im/news/security/
5. If you choose to compile, you simply install the dependencies, download and compile the code, and install Pidgin as follows:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep pidgin
sudo apt-get source pidgin
tar xjvf pidgin-2.x.y.tar.bz2
cd pidgin-2.x.y
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

If it fails for some reason, please refer to this page:
https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Installing%20Pidgin#WhycantIcompilePidgin
6. Right-click the system-tray icon of Pidgin and choose *Accounts*.
7. Add or modify your *Google Talk* account to have *Username* without @gmail.com or your own domain.
8. If you have your own domain for Google account, fill in the *Domain* field, otherwise there should be *gmail.com* present by default (without @).
9. The *Resource* is an XMPP specific thing that allows one to use several clients for the same account. Under normal circumstances leave blank.
10. Fill in the *Password* generated in step two.
11. Optional, but convenient, if on a secure computer, is ticking *Remember password*.
12. *Local alias* leave blank.
13. It should look like this:
[image: Adding Google Talk account to Pidgin]
14. On Advanced tab make sure you have *Require encryption* chosen and disabled *plaintext*.
15. Note, that after you save these settings, the protocol will automatically change to *XMPP*, which is currently available to third-party applications like Pidgin.

Comment: It might be helpful for some if you could also provide screenshots of these steps.