# How to add Google Hangout to Pidgin

Tags: pidgin, google-hangouts

I've been trying to add Google Hangouts to Pidgin but it's not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]
Before adding account to pidgin. Make sure google singin to less secure apps is allowed.

Or visit this link to enable Less Secure Apps
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

If it's done! Add Hangout account
#Basic Tab

```
Protocol: xmpp  
User Name: (your gmail id, without @gmail.com)  
Domain: gmail.com  
Resource: (Keep blank)  
Password: xxxxxxxxx  
Check Remember Password.
```

#Advanced Tab
[image]

```
Connection Security: Use encryption if available  
Connect Server: talk.google.com
```

Others leave at it is.

Done...!

Comment: Some context: https://xmpp.org/2015/03/no-its-not-the-end-of-xmpp-for-google-talk/

Comment: @Faisal Does this still work? I have tried and it says "unable to connect" ...

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 Yes it still works

Comment: Yes, for some reason it was not working at the beginning, now it works, many thanks! :)

Comment: I no longer see the "Less secure app access" section.

Comment: @DanDascalescu One direct link is given, you may access through that.

Comment: Ah, I get "This setting is not available for accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled." if I go to the direct link. That's why I wasn't seeing the setting.

Answer (score 2):

Pidgin seems to only support Google Talk - which uses a different protocol. Hangouts [employs](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2013/05/google-abandons-open-standards-instant-messaging) a proprietary protocol, not compatible with XMPP.

There is a cross-platform [client](https://github.com/yakyak/yakyak) designed specifically for Hangouts (partial support for audio-video), as well as a Python [library](https://hangups.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I found a solution in YakYak too. `sudo snap install yakyak` worked for me. Follow the on-screen prompts. It works even after the internal transition from Hangouts to Meet.